# How to pass json object to code behind in ASP.Net using VB

Tags: jquery, asp.net, json, ajax, vb.net

Can you help me to solve this..?

Actually I developed a simple application to pass a JSON object to ASP.Net code behind. I am Using VB in Code behind.

I am just using the below code in jquery ajax.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
      $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "form1.aspx/getStringReverse",
            data: "{'Name':'Vinoth'}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); }
            , failure: function (msg) { alert(msg.d); }
        });
});
```

Below is the code in VB

*'This code is not working*

```
<WebMethod>

Public Shared Function getStringReverse(ByVal name As String) As String

    Return StrReverse(name )

End Function
```

'This code is not working

When I am Calling this function, Control is not passed to the function.
But When I am changing this function as below, It works.

*'This code is working'*

```
<WebMethod>

 Public Shared Function getStringReverse() As String

    Return "String Reverse"

 End Function
```

'This code is working

Kindly help me to solve this.

Comment: There is a problem with the `StrReverse`-function. Can you post that code and also post the error message?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mark the method you want to call as WebMethod and also as static method.

```
 <WebMethod()>
    Public Shared Function getStringReverse(name as string) As String
        ***
    End Function
```